# "To know much about" en français

Tags: phrase

Comment traduirait-on la phrase suivante en français:

> My teachers at school know so much about the subjects that they teach

> Mes professeurs savent tellement sur les matières qu'ils enseignent?

Comment: Quel est le message que la phrase veut faire passer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mes professeurs **en** savent tellement sur les matières qu'ils enseignent.

> Mes professeurs sont tellement calés dans les matières qu'ils enseignent.